# scale image based on resoultion (aspect ratio)

Tags: image, math, image-processing, autohotkey, gdi+

I'm not sure how to ask this question in words without it becoming very confusing.  So I'll provide point form data to try and relay my issue.

- I've taken screenshots of the same image at different screen resolutions.
- This results in the image having different widths & heights.

[]

- img1.png

  - resolution = 1024×768
  - aspect ratio = 4:3
  - image = 43x43 pixels
- img2.png

  - resolution = 1280×1024
  - aspect ratio = 5:4
  - image = 57x57 pixels
- img3.png

  - resolution = 1920×1080
  - aspect ratio = 19:9
  - image = 60x60 pixels
- img4.png

  - resolution = 3440x1440
  - aspect ratio = 21:9
  - image = 80x80 pixels

[]

- we are given ONLY one of these four images
- we also have a different resolution then this image
- now find image = ??x?? pixels

[]

For sake of argument we have img3.png. Then change our resolution to 1280x1024. From here I can't figured out how to resize img3.png so that it knows it need to scale down to 57x57 instead of 60x60

- i could hard code

  - 4:3 = 0.716
  - 5:4 = 0.95
  - 21:9 = 1.33
- then i could use 60*0.95 = 57
- but i'm stubborn and want to be able to do this dynamically

[]

the reason behind this is so i can do an image search on different resolutions

Answer (score 0):

I assume the same square image is displayed on different screen resolutions, and based on some logic, it is shown a little bigger or smaller. Now your problem is, what's that logic?

Since it is always square, so it is not related to the aspect ratio. Then I guess the logic is trying to fit a square area, probably holding multiple of your small square image, to the rectangular screen. Since all these screens are landscape, then I would like to test the heights of each screen:

768:1024:1080:1440 = 0.533:0.711:0.75:1,

43:57:60:80 = 0.537:0.712:0.75:1

Got it? It's just scaled proportional to the height of the screen!

Comment: "Got it?"  nope lol i don't understand.

using the example of having img3.png and then we change our resolution to 1280x1024
how does one get the numbers 57x57

Comment: Then please explain more. I may have wrong assumptions. What are your img1, img2, img3's original dimension? What program are you using to display your images? Does the displaying program have some zoom function to control how big the images show up? Show some pictures, screenshots to explain your problem better.